# How to take a column of full dates (1/1/2015) and convert it to just the months (1) with VBA

Tags: vba, date

Using VBA I have an imported range of dates that I need to convert to months. The dates are in a column called DateCol. I have attached a sample of the code I'm using below.

Thanks

```
Dim DateColNum As Long
Dim ProfitColNum As Long
Dim StatusColNum As Long
Dim cell As Range


    DateColNum = Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(1).Find(What:="Purchased On", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False).Column

    ProfitColNum = Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(1).Find(What:="G.T. (Base)", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False).Column

    StatusColNum = Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(1).Find(What:="Status", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False).Column

''Convert to Column Letters 

DateCol = ColumnLetter(DateColNum) & ":" & ColumnLetter(DateColNum)
DateCell = ColumnLetter(DateColNum) & "1"  ''This is used to figure out the year
ProfitCol = ColumnLetter(ProfitColNum) & ":" & ColumnLetter(ProfitColNum)
StatusCol = ColumnLetter(StatusColNum) & ":" & ColumnLetter(StatusColNum)


''Start Figuring out stuff
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")


''Turn Dates to Month"

For Each cell In DateCol.Cells

 cell.Value = Month(cell.Value)

Next cell
```

Comment: And what's stopping you? :) Anyway, why do you need VBA? Just use the MONTH() function in Excel. Or use it in VBA.

Comment: It's only because I have to do it to a ton of documents. Loads of csv files that I import from Google Analytic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Month() function - either in excel, or in VBA.

For example:

```
activecell.value=month(activecell.value)
```

Put it in a loop, for example:

```
for each youAreLazy in selection.cells
 youAreLazy.value=month(youAreLazy.value)
next youAreLazy
```

Comment: So for the range of DateCol. I would do  for each i in DateCol.range?

Comment: I tried `for each i in Range(DateCol).cells   i.value = month(i.value) next i ` and got a type mismatch.

Comment: well, that should work, provided that DateCol is a valid range.

Comment: @user3594544 is DateCol a named range?  Just because it has the column heading DateCol it is not name as such.  Excel does not have named columns.  You will need to look into how to dynamically refere to a range.  You will need to refer to the range by its column letter; Range("E1:E10000").  Do some homework on google and come back with a new question that is specific has an example of what you have tried and what it is doing that is incorrect.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. DateCol is a Variable representing whatever column the dates happen to be in since it varies with each document. So it could be = C:C. It's actually not a range just the column.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you absolutely need to use `Cells()` instead of trying to change numbers to letters.

```
Dim DateColNum As Long
Dim ProfitColNum As Long
Dim StatusColNum As Long
Dim cell As Range
Dim DateCol As Range
Dim DateCell As Range
Dim ProfitCol As Range
Dim StatusCol As Range

    DateColNum = Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(1).Find(What:="Purchased On", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False).Column

    ProfitColNum = Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(1).Find(What:="G.T. (Base)", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False).Column

    StatusColNum = Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(1).Find(What:="Status", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False).Column


With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set DateCol = .Range(.Cells(2, DateColNum), .Cells(2, datcolnum).End(xlDown))
    Set DateCell = .Cells(1, DateColNum) ''This is used to figure out the year
    Set ProfitCol = .Range(.Cells(2, ProfitColNum), .Cells(2, ProfitColNum).End(xlDown))
    Set StatusCol = .Range(.Cells(2, StatusColNum), .Cells(2, StatusColNum).End(xlDown))


    ''Start Figuring out stuff



    ''Turn Dates to Month"

    For Each cell In DateCol.Cells
     cell.Value = Month(cell.Value)
    Next cell
End With
```

I also changed your strings to ranges and used `set` to set them to the exact area wanted.  You do not want to use the entire column as it will search over 1 million lines and throw errors when it gets to empty cells.

This will still throw an error if the cell does not contain a date, but it should give you the backbone on which to proceed.

Comment: @Cazforshort You should accept Vicap's answer as correct as it technically answered your first question.